# How to create stored procedure which returns text without vowels

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I need create stored function to remove vowels from any given text string and return text without vocals.

Have syntax to remove vowels, but don't know how to create stored function

```
REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (text, 'E', ''), 'Y', ''), 'U', ''), 'I', ''), 'O', ''), 'A', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to find and remove the letters you do not want. The regexp_replace function finds a particular pattern and replaces with a something different. In your case, something like this may work:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('abc def ghi', '[aeiouyAEIOUY]', '');
```

The documentation on using regular expressions in mysql can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Creating a function for this would be something like:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION removeVowels(OrigString VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) 
     BEGIN 
         RETURN (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(OrigString, '[aeiouyAEIOUY]', ''););
     END;
```

A quick tutorial on MySql functions can be found [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/)